# Tabela sobre Cabeçalho e Rodapé no mPDF

Tags: php, mpdf

Estou com um pdf gerado pelo mPDF que a tabela esta sobrepondo o meu cabeçalho e o rodapé.
Coloquei o codigo no Gits.
[inserir a descrição do link aqui](https://gist.github.com/FabricioYwin/3c90dccc16a165632aa62cfb4f69e980)

Como resolver isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já tentou tirar as tags `<html>` e `<head>` ?

Comment: Sim.
Deu no mesmo.

Comment: Tive uma evolução alterando $mpdf = new mPDF();
mas o cabeçalho ainda está trepando.

Answer (score 1):

Os quatro últimos número são respectivamente margem esquerda, direita, superior e inferior.

**Cada um deve ajustar de acordo com o seu relatório.**

```
$mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8', 'A4-L',7,'MS Serif',5,5,27,5);
```